# Why drop down option not display using angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to make simple application from this like
https://github.com/nimbly/angular-formly
I am able to generate the  form from json.my problem is that I am not able to display option of drop down.As I I read the document .but I don't know where I am wrong..?

```
"inputValues": {
                    "True": "true",
                    "False": "false"
                },
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/tuMl02QcvZkCCIJPTW0r?p=preview.
When user click the button it show the form .In that there is  parameter "add" which is drop down.I saw the documentation it is taking **option** as a key so I change input values to key .

I have two option true and false but it not display.
Secondly there is four field it display only three why ?

Comment: Your form config doesn't match the example given in the document.

Comment: I change the con config using change method.please check my change method changeData

Comment: Yeah, it still doesn't match. The `options` config for select tag in the document is an Array containing objects with property `name`. But your config is an Object.

Comment: ok wait checking..!! and why it show three field ..?

Comment: There is no input type `'EMAIL'` in your `map` variable.

Comment: secondly how we manage key and value ?.mean if I want to show "TRUE" and it value is "TEST" then how it is posible

Comment: Here I have   "login": {
                "displayDetail": "Password for login.",
                "displayName": "Loginuuuu *",
                "inputType": "EMAIL",
                "name": "logi",
                "value": "pQE",
                "unit": "NONE",
                "required": true,
                "visible": true
            },

Comment: so can you please tell me how I will show drop down ?